# Best way to run 3.3V circuit for long time using 3 AAA batteries?

Tags: batteries, low-power

I have a circuit that is off almost all the time, when a button is pressed an MCU will be brought outside of sleep mode perform a log and go back to sleep. This device should run on 3 1.5V AAA batteries giving more than 3.3V.

How can I regulate the voltage when I wake up from sleep and have the regulator not waste energy when device is not used?

Comment: Depends what causes you to wake up from sleep...

Comment: @vicatcu A button press brings the MCU out of sleep mode. The button generates an asynchronous external interrupt request by changing the logic state of one of the MCU's pins.

Comment: Yeah but you have to supply the MCU 3.3v before it can receive interrupt, right?

Comment: @user3528438 Yes, that's the main part of the question :)

Comment: does the mcu need to be on during "sleep" our could power be removed completely in principle

Comment: @vicatcu It could turned off, however the button that is pressed to wake it up is a momentary button. I can not add a relay in order to control power. The power usage should remain as low as possible.

Comment: Ideally you would use a mosfet circuit that the button energized and then the mcu could _keep_ energized for as long as it wanted, and could then shut down

Comment: @vicatcu And what about the regulator required?

Comment: A switching regulator ideally, but it depends on your design constraints.

Comment: is it an ESP8266? i run mine on 2AA, since it tolerates down to ~2.8v

Answer (score 1):

If you use a CMOS flip/flop, the 'button press' can SET the
flip/flop, which can enable a low-dropout regulator like
[TPS706](http://www.ti.com/product/tps706/datasheet)  .   The regulator turns on, your MCU
goes through power-on operations, does its thing, and
turns the power off by issuing a RESET to the flip/flop.
When in 'shutdown', that TPS706 takes under 150 nA.

This is usually needless, though: many MCU chips have a
variety of on-chip functions to go into sleep mode.
A trio of alkaline AAA cells has roughly 1200 mAh of capacity,
so a modest drain (like, 30 uA) might be supportable.
30 uA will drain the cells in a bit over 4 years,
and 150 nA will take longer (so long that battery shelf-life
dominates).